# Rootless docker causes "failed to resolve address for github.com"

Tags: linux, docker, rust, rust-cargo

In my dockerfile i'm installing cryptography python dependency however when building wheel from rootless docker i'm getting following error:

```
...
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c'
  running build_rust
      Updating crates.io index
  warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Name does not resolve; class=Net (12)
  warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Name does not resolve; class=Net (12)
  error: failed to get `pyo3` as a dependency of package `cryptography-rust v0.1.0 (/tmp/pip-install-h22hlaqn/cryptography_a2037904c10949639ccf8a3b2519f187/src/rust)`
  
  Caused by:
    failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
  
  Caused by:
    network failure seems to have happened
    if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
    https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli
  
  Caused by:
    failed to resolve address for github.com: Name does not resolve; class=Net (12)
  
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
      5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
         set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  

...
```

The strangest thing that the same dockerfile compiles absolutely successfully when built from root user.
I'm using the most recent docker version on arch linux and have tried following instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ and installing AUR and in both cases had no luck.
That's my docker file:

```
FROM        python:3.7-alpine

ENV         LANG C.UTF-8

RUN         apk update \
            && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc g++ musl-dev python3 python3-dev autoconf automake linux-headers make libffi-dev openssl-dev \
            && apk add --no-cache bash postgresql-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev git openssh-client rust cargo

RUN         mkdir -p /opt/carryall/app
RUN         mkdir -p /opt/carryall/static
RUN         mkdir -p /opt/carryall/media

WORKDIR     /opt/carryall/app

RUN         mkdir /root/.ssh/
ADD         id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa_temp
RUN         cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa_temp | tr -d '\r' > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN         chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN         touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN         ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

ADD         requirements.txt /opt/carryall/app/
RUN         pip install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/carryall/app/requirements.txt

RUN         apk del --purge build-deps \
            && rm -rf /root/.cache /tmp/*

ADD         . /opt/carryall/app
```

Comment: Posting the dockerfile would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated question to contain dockerfile if it might give any hints about the problem.

Comment: Can you do DNS resolution in general inside the container when run as non-root? (e.g. would a curl https://github.com work?) Searching "rootless docker dns resolution" seems to show significant challenges around it in certain cases.